# Multiple divs fade in/ out on scroll effect not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a 3 `div`s which are relatively positioned on the right side of my page inside an absolute parent div. I want them fade in and out as they scroll outside of they view (parent div). The fade feature was working before I set my parent `div`s positioning. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance for any help!

Here is a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Jdoyle112/pen/mVOBJm)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="left_content">
            <img src="buffalo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="content">
            <div class="right_content" id="box1">
                <h4>Hi. My name is Jack.</h4>
                <p>Scroll down for more info</p>
            </div>
            <div class="right_content" id="box2">
                <h4>I'm a 21 year old developer living in Buffalo, Ny.</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="right_content" id="box3">
                <h4>Hi. My name is Jack.</h4>
                <p>Scroll down for more info</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('[id^="box"]').each(function () {
        if (($(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) < 20) {
             $(this).stop().fadeTo(100, .5);
        } else {
             $(this).stop().fadeTo('fast', 1);
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#left_content {
     position: fixed;
}
.right_content {
     position: relative;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
     display: none;
}
#content {
     width: 45%;
     height: 400px;
     overflow: scroll;
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
}
h4, p {
     margin-left: 10%;
}
#box1 {
     top: 250px;
}
#box2 {
     top: 650px;
}
#box3 {
     top: 1050px;
     margin-bottom: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.scroll()` is not on the proper area. Because you are actually scrolling your `<div id="content">` and not the window itself, so adjust your script like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#content').scroll(function () {
        $('[id^="box"]').each(function () {
            if (($(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) < 20) {
                $(this).stop().fadeTo(100, 0.5);
            } else {
                $(this).stop().fadeTo('fast', 1);
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```